# Contradiction? Getting a complex Fourier variable when solving the Helmholtz equation in lossy media

Tags: electromagnetism, fourier-transform, complex-numbers, differential-equations, dissipation

I want to find the general solution of the Helmholtz equation in the context of electromagentism
$$(\nabla^2+n(\omega)^2\omega^2)\hat{E}(\omega, \vec{r})=0$$
For this I tried Fourier transforming the solution
$$\hat{E}(\omega,\vec{r})=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}^3}\int d^3\vec{k}\tilde{E}(\omega, \vec{k})\textrm{e}^{i\vec{k}\vec{r}}$$
This leads to
$$
\vec{k}^2=\frac{n^2}{c^2}\omega^2
$$
And I feel like this is a contradiction.. My fourier paramtere $\vec{k}$ should be real, but as $n$ is complex in general it can't be. So what did I do wrong? Where's the flaw in my thinking, I really can't get my head around this, thought the entire day about it actually.

Comment: the complex $k$ means that the medium is lossy and the amplitude of the wave is exponentially decaying with spatial decay rate being the imag part of $k$

Comment: also, if $\Re{[ik]}<0$ then the Fourier transform can be extended analytically to that half-plane from the real line and you can "freely" use most anything you have already learnt about the transform itself.

Comment: @hyportnex yes this physical interpretation I know. But I always had in my head that we can "decompose" any function in plain waves with real "fourier variables" (I know this is not the technical term.. it was something with conjugate variable I think). Is this wrong, do we need for some functions, e.g. the solution of this equation, complex fourier variables? Thanks for your help

Comment: You should take $k$ real, and $\omega$ complex. The imaginary part of $\omega$ means things decay over time.

Comment: to the extent I understand what you are asking there is the time-domain analogy with Laplace Transform. You can interpret that as a sum of decaying exponentials though I have not seen any use of that interpretation. The analytic extension of FT to LT is important because it allows you to understand the function by its poles and zeros.

Comment: @knzhou the way I understood the question: $\omega$ is real but $n(\omega)$ is complex

Comment: @knzhou Okay but this doesn't solve the issue.. The $\omega$ arises also in a fourier transform (time-frequency). So I also have a compley fourier variable that way.. I always have at least one complex one. And I find this weird. I'm only used to real ones and didn't think one needs complex ones.. Of course I can just ignore this in my text and say "oh look, now \vec{k}$ is complex", but withouth understanding it, it seems like cheating to me.

Comment: @hyportnex Yes, actually I would like to chose $\omega$ as real